# Why is grep not finding string when definitely in file?

Tags: python, regex, grep

First time posting and a bit of a noob so if any problems with etiquette or formatting then do let me know.

I'm trying to use the grep function on the file (image below) to check if a word is present in a file. The word is definitely present as I've viewed the file. It's surrounded by spaces and is the last word in a line.

For some reason, grep can't find the word and the programme is returning 0. Why?

Thanks!

```
import os
import re

word = "aliows"
folder = '/Users/jordanfreedman/Thinkful/Projects/Spam_Filter/enron1/spam/'
email = '4201.2005-04-05.GP.spam.txt'

number = int(os.popen("grep -w -i -l " + word + " " + folder + email + " | wc -l").read())
print number
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the number of times `word` appears in the text file?

Comment: What happens when you run your `grep` command on the command line?

Comment: If you run that command in the shell manually does it work? Can you `grep` for something else on that line and pipe the output to `xxd` or `hexdump`?

Comment: the problem is the pipe. `popen` doesn't recognize pipe so `|` is considered as a single argument, which is not intended.

Comment: @IanAuld Just to see if the word is present in the file at all

Comment: @MattDMo Same problem unfortunately. Still getting 0.

Comment: You imported `re`, use it.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr **wrong** `os.popen()` runs the shell and therefore the pipe | is recognized

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to post a snip of the file so we can test the `grep` statement. Also, there's no reason to shell out:

```
import re

word = "aliows"
folder = '/Users/jordanfreedman/Thinkful/Projects/Spam_Filter/enron1/spam/'
email = '4201.2005-04-05.GP.spam.txt'

file = folder + email
fh = open(file, 'r')

contents = re.findall(word, fh.read())

print(len(contents))
```

Comment: I think this works - thanks! Let me try it on my main programme (which loops through all files)...

Comment: the code treats `word` as a regex that might not be desirable. You haven't implemented `-w` (match at word boundaries), `-l` (early exit), `-i` (ignore case). There is no need to load the whole file into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could find out whether there is a match using the exit status:

```
import os
from subprocess import STDOUT, call

path = os.path.join(folder, email)
with open(os.devnull, 'wb', 0) as devnull:
   rc = call(['grep', '-w', '-l', '-i', '-F', word, path],
             stdout=devnull, stderr=STDOUT)
if rc == 0: 
    print('found')
elif rc == 1:
    print('not found')
else:
    print('error')
```

Or [as @stevieb mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32121953/4279), you could find whether the word is in a given file in pure Python:

```
import re
from contextlib import closing
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap

with open(path) as f, closing(mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ)) as m:
   if re.search(br"(?i)\b%s\b" % re.escape(word), m):
       print('found')
```